# What's the quickest way to wipe off the poison goo?

Tags: batman-arkham-city-lockdown

When fighting Joker, he will occasionally cover Batman's face with poison goo, which you then have to swipe away.  If you can remove the goo in less than 5 seconds, you earn the *Last Laugh* achievement.  **What's the best technique to quickly wipe away the goo?  Is there anyway you can dodge the goo attack?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally earned this trophy.  I used my index finger, extended across the entire screen, then wiped left-to-right in short quick strikes.  It also seemed that pressing against the screen harder wiped more goo away.